# Fatal Error during installation of WebLogic Server

Tags: installation, weblogic12c

I am trying to install WebLogic Server on my mac, and it "Encounter's a Fatal Error" at exactly 37% of the installation process. I am not the only one having these problems in my class. Does anybody have any experience/advice on how to deal with this/how to figure out what the problem is? Thanks!

Added:
I just want to add that in the lower left-hand corner of the installer it says "installing…com.bea.cie.oui_1.1.0.0.jar" Just in case that helps somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following and check the **log file** also see if you have enough space in your installation location:

```
-log=log.out -log_priority=debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem with this article:

"Suppose your user is named « Fred », and that the JDeveloper installer is on your desktop. You can execute the following command in a terminal window (on a single line) to start the installer:

/usr/libexec/java_home --version 1.6.0 
 --exec java -jar /Users/Fred/Desktop/jdevstudio11116install.jar"

https://blogs.oracle.com/blueberry/entry/how_to_saddle_your_mountain

Answer (score -1):

If you get a java.io.FileNotFoundException check your antivirus